# C Programming for 8051: SFR directions as arguments

Tags: c, 8051

I'm currently making a very simple Tic-Tac-Toe game with an AT89C51RC2 and I am having issues getting the button input right.

Basically, the input is a 3x3 Button Matrix which I want to utilize by scanning through the rows with a pulse while checking the columns for a connection; pretty basic. However, the way I wanted to do this was by making a unique *scroll* method that received the row parameter and set it to HIGH accordingly.

I already have

```
sbit R1 = P1^0;
```

all through the needed inputs, but I'm not sure if this is correct.

Then, on my main method, I run something like

```
while(TRUE)
{
    scroll(R1);
}
```

which is named scroll, I have this

```
void scroll (bit P)
{
   P = HIGH; //Sets the row being checked to HIGH (HIGH is already defined as a 1). Same goes with the aformentioned TRUE
   ...
}
```

So, this is not working. I know I'm not doing this right, but I had to start somewhere. Is what I am attempting to do possible? Sending a single Pin adress as an overload for a method? If so, what datatype should it be? I was juggling between char and bit but I can't settle.

I hope my question is understandable! If not, I will gladly elaborate and maybe post all the code (although it is quite messy). Thanks, everyone, in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit: I changed code example to answer your question much better**

I never used that chip, but it looks like a 8 bit variant of the 8051, so I would make the following guess: your port are defined as "sfr".  Usually your MCU header file contains definitions such as :

```
sfr P1=0x90;
```

As per your chip's [datasheet](http://www.atmel.ca/Images/doc4180.pdf) on page 5, P1 is at address 0x90.  So that means that you could write something like that:

```
unsigned char scroll(sbit pin);

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
 sbit pinMap[3]={P0^6,P0^7,P1^0}; // P0.6, P0.7 and P1.0.
 char keyboardRows[3]; // Keyboard layout is: one row per byte.  Column are mapped on 0 to 2.
 int i;

 while(1)
 {
  for(i=0;i<3;++i)
  {
   scroll(pinMap[i]);
  }
 }

 return 0;
}

unsigned char scroll(sbit pin)
{
 unsigned char rowState;
 pin=1; // or HIGH.

 // Save your column state in rowState here.

 pin=0; // or LOW?

 return rowState;
}
```

Now, an you didn't say what kind of problem you were having.  We need more information to help you out.

1. Is it software or could it be hardware?
   *software*
2. What kind of error are you getting?
   *I'm still not sure other than it doesn't work*
3. It doesn't compile?
   *It is fine.*
4. It doesn't do what you **expect**?
   *I still don't know what you get vs. what you expect.*
5. Is it a custom matrix?
   *Yes and it works.*
6. Is so, have you used pull up resistors to set a definite state when the buttons are not pressed?
   *It's ok.*
7. Have to put diode to prevent ghost keys to appear (when pressing many keys at once)?
   *It's ok.*

**Edit:  Ok, your compiler don't like sbit as parameter, so one may try this:**

```
unsigned char scroll(unsigned char* port,unsigned char pin);

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
 unsigned char* portAddr={&P0,&P1,&P2}; // Put whatever here.
 unsigned char pin[3]={0x40,0x80,0x01}; // P0.6, P0.7 and P1.0.
 char keyboardRows[3]; // Keyboard layout is: one row per byte.  Column are mapped on 0 to 2.
 int i;

 while(1)
 {
  for(i=0;i<3;++i)
  {
   scroll(portAddr[i],pinMap[i]);
  }
 }

 return 0;
}

unsigned char scroll(unsigned char* port,unsigned char pin)
{
 unsigned char rowState;
 *port|=pin; // Let the bus weak pull-up pull the bus up.

 // Save your column state in rowState here.

 *port&=~pin; // Drive low the output.

 return rowState;
}
```

If you really insist on using sbit and such things, you could make the declaration global such as this:

```
sbit RowPins[3]={P0^6,P0^7,P1^0};

unsigned char scroll(int rowIndex);

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
 char keyboardRows[3]; // Keyboard layout is: one row per byte.  Column are mapped on 0 to 2.
 int i;

 while(1)
 {
  for(i=0;i<3;++i)
  {
   scroll(i);
  }
 }

 return 0;
}

unsigned char scroll(int rowIndex)
{
 RowPins[i]=HIGH;

 // Read stuff here and put in "column".

 RowPins[i]=LOW;

 return column;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer and researching. Although the program is compiling, it's not doing what I would want it to do. I guess the more solid question is:
Now that I've already donde sbit R1 = P0^0, what is R1's data type? I want to know so I can use R1 as a parameter in a method. As stated in the problem, I want to do this so I can run a "scroll" method which scans the columns with the same method, once for R1, once for R2 and once for R3.

Comment: Also, the resistors and ghosting thing is sorted, the button matrix is made with spst push buttons. The only issue I have is with this piece of code.

Comment: @BretonDP I edited my answer to reflect new information provided.

Comment: I see! So basically, you sent an sbit as the argument, which is what I was trying to achieve, and then used sbit again as the parameter. I tried doing so, but it wouldn't let me make scroll receive an sbit for some reason. I will try to make a piece of code similar to you, arrays and all, and give it a try. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Miyoshi I have attempted to follow your code, but it seems that sbit cannot be used within functions or as parameters.

Comment: Well, if your compiler do not support sbit as parameters, you will have to use the first solution that I had proposed: passing the address of the register and doing the magic by hand.  I'll put an example.